# How to create bat file that zip all folders using winzip?

Tags: windows, batch-file, compression

I want to create a bat file that compresses all the folders inside a specific directory and then deletes them.
For example,
Folder structure (before running bat file):

```
VidoesArch
      January
      February
      March
      ....
  TextualArch
      January
      February
      March
      ....


Folder structure (after running bat file):
  VideosArch
      January.zip
      February.zip
      March.zip
      ....
  TextualArch
      January.zip
      February.zip
      March.zip
      ....
```

This what I have developed so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set INPBKP=C:\Data\Backup\VideosArch
set OUTBKP=C:\Data\Backup\TextualArch
set WZLOC=C:\PROGRA~2\WINZIP

:: Caution: Use a drive where sufficient disk space is available for this setting.
set WORKDIR=K:\

:: DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BEYOND THIS POINT

set COMPCMD="%WZLOC%\WZZIP.EXE" -m -ex -b%WORKDIR% -a 

for /F "USEBACKQ DELIMS==" %%t in (`dir %INPBKP%\*.dat /a/s/b`) do @%COMPCMD% %%t.zip %%t
for /F "USEBACKQ DELIMS==" %%t in (`dir %OUTBKP%\*.dat /a/s/b`) do @%COMPCMD% %%t.zip %%t

endlocal
```

What this file does is, it zip all the .dat files in the folders. What I want to achieve is it shall zip all the folders.

Update:

I have changed the file content and now it looks like this. Its not working. If I try to run on command prompt it says- 'The system cannot find the file specified'.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set INPBKP=C:\Data\Backup\VideosArch
set OUTBKP=C:\Data\Backup\TextualArch
set WZLOC=C:\PROGRA~2\WINZIP

:: Caution: Use a drive where sufficient disk space is available for this setting.
set WORKDIR=C:\

:: DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BEYOND THIS POINT

set COMPCMD="%WZLOC%\WZZIP64.EXE" -r -p -m -ex -b%WORKDIR%

for %%s in ("%INPBKP%" "%OUTBKP%") do for /F "DELIMS==" %%t in ('dir %%s /ad /b') do %COMPCMD% %%~nt.zip "%%~s\%%t"

endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set COMPCMD="%WZLOC%\WZZIP.EXE" -r -p -m -ex -b%WORKDIR%

for /F "DELIMS==" %%t in ('dir %INPBKP% /ad /b') do %COMPCMD% "%INPBKP%\%%~nt.zip" %INPBKP%\%%t
```

Adding `-r -p` to the compress command should gather and retain all the files and directories.

By executing `dir /b /ad`, `%%t` will be assigned the directorynames from the target directory. `%%~nt` selects simply the name part. The `usebackq` is not required if single quotes are used.

You could possibly also use

```
for %%s in ("%INPBKP%" "%OUTBKP%") do for /F "DELIMS=" %%t in ('dir /ad /b %%s') do %COMPCMD% "%%~s\%%~nt.zip" "%%~s\%%t"
```

`%%s` containing the quoted directoryname and `%%~s` unquoted (in case of separators in directorynames)

I haven't tested this, so I'd suggest you try it on some disposible test directories first.

[edit - to insert the destination directory for the `zip` file]
[also changed `delims==` to `delims=` (cosmetic - change `=` as delimiter to no delimiter)]

Comment: Sadly "not working" doesn't provide many clues. It zipped the contents of every subdirectory of the two nominated directories into *nominated*\subdirname.zip for me.

Comment: Its working. Giving around 90% compression ratio. Thanks.

Comment: It is working fine. But it deletes the data to recycle bin. I want to delete data completely. Could you please check it.

Comment: Could you please reply to the above comment. I have zero knowledge of this language.

Comment: The `wzzip.exe` utility does not have the facility to wipe files. Neither does 7Zip. The philosophy is that if there's some corruption in creating the archive, you will have lost the original files. Wzzip "recycles" them, 7Zip leaves them exactly where they are (it has no **M**ove facility).There *are* utilities that will clear your "recycle bin" - but if you automatically run that after having ziiped your dat, then you can't recover in the case of a corruption and it will clear all entries from the bin - not just those relating to your `zip` operation.